# How do I get a connection from Anchor?

Tags: web3.js, anchor-client

I'm used to the Solana web3.js library, but have recently started using Anchor.

I can see Anchor's TS client connects to my local cluster when I run my transaction, but how do I get the normal web3.js `connection` object from Anchor?

Answer (score 1):

You can load the provider with

`const provider = getProvider() as AnchorProvider;`

and now you can access `provider.connection`.

You may also be interested in the wallet `const wallet = provider.wallet as Wallet;`

Comment: Thanks for answering! This seems like the same answer - provider.connection - as the older answer above though.

Answer (score -1):

**Answering my own question to help others**

The `connection` can be accessed through

`const connection = program.provider.connection;`

I can't find any information about Anchor Providers on the [Anchor website](https://www.anchor-lang.com/) but I did find a [doc describing Anchor Providers at the Anchor GitHub](https://coral-xyz.github.io/anchor/ts/classes/AnchorProvider.html).

Comment: Downvoter - is there anything I can do to improve my answer?